# Lerna is not rendering inquirer prompt properly

Tags: typescript, lerna, inquirerjs

I am using lerna to handle the monorepo project structure.

When I run below code

```
const question = [{
       type: 'input',
       name: 'permission',
       message: chalk.red(logMessages.deleteFeatureReleaseBranch.permissionMessage),
       filter: (input: string) => {
            return input.trim();
       },
       validate: (input: string) => {
         if (!validatePermissionInput(input)) return logMessages.deleteFeatureReleaseBranch.permissionValidationFailedMessage;
              return true;
          }
}];

const permission:string = (await inquirer.prompt(question)).permission;
```

- **from the perticular project directory with simple node.js command `node dist/src/index.js delete-feature -r`**
  It is showing the proper output as
  `Are you sure you want to delete these branches(Y|N):`
- **But when i run the command from the root directory as lerna command like `lerna run start --scope=cli-app -- delete-feature -r`**
  It is not showing the prompt question like above. But when I force close the application or give random input which is failing validation, then it is showing the prompt question.

I don't know whether the issue is with inquirer (like extra configuration for lerna support) or it is the lerna not supporting inquirer prompt question.

Comment: I'm guessing you might be on Windows, someone told me he had problems with Inquirer and I know he's on Windows so... I'm just guessing but perhaps you're not using powershell? Try changing shell or look at Inquirer GitHub issue page

Comment: yes I am using powershell and I am using windows as well. And I found the issue in lerna github. Actually lerna was not supporting inquirer in v5 but they stated that the issue is now resolved by merging one pr they linked in the comment of related issue. But I am still getting the error. Is this the issue with powershell?

Comment: I always use powershell in VSCode terminal and never had problem with [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) and its dependencies are updated very often, so it does use the latest Inquirer

Comment: I tried with the command prompt and powershell.  Both are not useful to render inquirer. However I am running it from the inside project folder till I found the solution.

Comment: The github issue was stating that stdio:"inherit" was removed. that is why inquirer is giving error. Can you help me how set stdio:"inherit" to inherit standard input output from console. If there is any configuration in lerna.json or nx.json.
Thank you.